# Why does my while loop with an if statement not work properly?

Tags: javascript

i am trying to code a to do list in java script, where a prompt will ask the user what they want to do and then the user has 3 options, either "new" to add a new element or "list" to check the elements already added or "quit" to quit the loop.

i tried changing the syntax by changing the position of the semicolons but it only resulted in a never ending loop which crashes my laptop!

```
var todo=[];
var answer=prompt("what do you want to do?");
while (answer!=="quit") {
  if (answer=="list") {
    console.log(todo);
  }
  else if (answer="new") {
    var newtodo=prompt("what do you want to add?");
    todo.push(newtodo);


  }
}
alert("ok we're done here");
```

when i open the HTML file that my script is attached to, the first prompt appears as expected, when i type in "quit" it quits the loop as expected and shows the alert but when i type in "new" it keeps asking me what do u want to add? no matter what i type and it just never ends. Also when i type in list it keeps asking me what do u want to add even though it's supposed to list my array. i think i have done a mistake in the syntax but i don't know what.

Comment: `else if (answer="new")` You probably want more than 1 `=` there.

Comment: Once you entered the `while` loop, how will be `answer` updated so the loop condition can become eventually `false`? Think about that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that **you are only prompting once**, before the while loop.

Fix: at the end of the while, prompt again:

```
var answer=prompt("what do you want to do?");
while (answer!=="quit") {
  if (answer=="list") {
    console.log(todo);
  }
  else if (answer=="new") { //plus here it's '==', not '='
    var newtodo=prompt("what do you want to add?");
    todo.push(newtodo);
  }
  answer=prompt("what do you want to do?");
}
```